# Quit an Infinite loop

Tags: java, daemon, infinite-loop

So I have a daemon that just constantly runs so I put a while(true). The problem is that there may come a time when it needs to be shut down. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If it quits, it's no longer infinite ... :(

Comment: This question is so under-specified: the wide range of answers below show this. Consider posting a *minimal* example and further explanation. E.g. is it multi-threaded? Is there a "controller" thread? What signals "when it needs to be shut down"? Etc.

Comment: Okay, moving to vote as "Not a Real Question", perhaps it can be turned into one.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of an infinite loop, do something like this:

```
private volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

//... your main loop 
   while(keepRunning) {
   }


//...
public void triggerShutdown() {
   keepRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: @pst: Why would the above break if they were on the same thread?  Looks entirely safe either way to me.  `triggerShutdown()` won't block so it doesn't matter if it's called from within the infinite loop.

Comment: True. I assumed that `triggerShutdown` could never be triggered from within the `while...`, but there is nothing inherent in the [vague] post or your answer to limit it.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(true) {
   // code code code
   // more code

   if(quitcondition)
      break;

   // more code
}
```

Comment: Why not just `while(!quitecondition) { ... }`?

Comment: This way you can quit in the middle of a loop, as opposed to only at the beginning. Plus seeing `while(true)` gives a hint to the next guy working on your code that it's a long-running loop.

Comment: +1 Fair enough -- even if I *really dislike* this construct, this was the only answer using `break` that also showed code before.

Answer (score 2):

You can exit the loop with a `break;` statement.

```
while (true)
{
    if (exitCondition)
    {
        break;
    }
    //other work
}
```

Comment: @au2al: this is true, break is the key statement.

Comment: Why not just `while(!exitCondition) { ... }`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the interrupted status of the deamon thread

```
public class StoppableTask extends Runnable{

  private Thread thr;

  public StoppableTask(){

  }

  public void run() {
    try{
        while (true) {
          // do some stuff...
          if(Thread.interrupted())throw new InterruptedException();
          //do some more stuf
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        return;//we expect this and just stop when we get it
    }
  }

  public void tellMeToStop() {
    thr.interrupt();
  }

  public void start(){
     if(thr!=null)return;
     thr = new Thread(this);
     thr.setDeamon(true);
     thr.start();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StoppableTask t = new StoppableTask();
    t.start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    br.readLine();
    t.tellMeToStop();
}
```

note that it is important to propagate the Interrupted exceptions (or reset the interrupted status with `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`) from called methods down to the while loop for this to have effect

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have an exit condition that contains the statement `break`.

```
while(true){
    if(condition){
        break;
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Why not just `while(!condition) { ... }`?

Comment: Since he stated that his loop used `while(true)` and nothing else I was working off that.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the thread to be interrupted, instead of creating another flag to stop it.

```
// will leave the interrupt flag.
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {  

}
```

or

```
while(!Thread.interrupted()) { // will clear the interrupt flag.

}
```

Comment: `Thread.interrupted()` is static no need to call `currentThread()` first

Comment: @ratchet, Thanks, got two alternative mixed up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use multi-threading to solve this issue.  It is suggested that you use volatile variables for your flag to prevent threading issues.

```
public class StoppableTask extends Thread {
  private volatile boolean pleaseStop;

  public void run() {
    while (!pleaseStop) {
      // do some stuff...
    }
  }

  public void tellMeToStop() {
    pleaseStop = true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StoppableTask t = new StoppableTask()
    t.Start();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    br.readLine();
    t.tellMeToStop();
}
```

This would stop after you enter any text on the command line.

Comment: You don't *necessarily* need multithreading (the question is so under-specified). As long as the stop condition can be signaled...